# Does heroku app have to share the same name as django project?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app that I started with `django-admin startproject workout`. Months later, it was time to deploy, `workout` was not an available name for heroku apps. Thus, I decided on `shworkout`. Now, I'm having problems with the deployment. Take a look at this traceback:

```
2018-01-15T13:50:49.922410+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn shworkout.wsgi --log-file -`
2018-01-15T13:50:52.274803+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2018-01-15T13:50:52.275393+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:57296 (4)
2018-01-15T13:50:52.275484+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-01-15T13:50:52.278566+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283407+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283421+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283428+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283430+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283431+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283433+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283432+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283434+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283443+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283441+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283442+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283446+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283448+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283444+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283445+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283449+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shworkout'
2018-01-15T13:50:52.315187+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283447+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283527+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-01-15T13:50:52.315111+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-01-15 13:50:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-01-15T13:50:52.401600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-01-15T13:50:52.415493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The lines

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-01-15T13:50:52.283449+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shworkout'
```

are what catch my attention the most. My guess is this: gunicorn is looking for a wsgi.py file (it's in `/workout`), but it's looking for it in the wrong place, namely, a folder called `/shworkout`. Such a folder doesn't exist in my project. `shworkout` is only a name for my app *on heroku*.

So, is this a correct explanation? What to do about it then? And if I'm wrong, what is really going on here?

**Procfile**:

```
web: gunicorn shworkout.wsgi --log-file -
```

Should I change `shworkout` to `workout`?

**wsgi.py**:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "workout.settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: You need to show your Procfile and your wsgi file.

Comment: I changed from `shworkout` to `workout`. That was the problem, bad Procfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a faulty Procfile. Changed from:

```
web: gunicorn shworkout.wsgi --log-file -
```

to

```
web: gunicorn workout.wsgi --log-file -
```

Explanation:

the Procfile should point to the location of the wsgi.py file, which is in `/workout`, not in `/shworkout`.